# stratification in cox model

Tags: r, survival, cox-model

I am trying to understand difference in output between the following lines of code:

```
library(survival)

summary(coxph(Surv(futime, fustat) ~ age + strata(rx), data=ovarian))
summary(coxph(Surv(futime, fustat) ~ age, data=ovarian))
```

What does adding `strata(rx)` do? 
Explanation `?strata` says:

```
**Value**
a new factor, whose levels are all possible combinations
of the factors supplied as arguments.
```

What is the point to take all possible combinations of factor values, when they are mutually exclusive. What am I missing? Why example contains `strata(rx)` i.e. only one factor, when explanation is talking about interaction of factors?

Comment: The explanation is a general one: one factor is a special case of the interaction between factors.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In a Cox model, stratification allows for as many different hazard functions as there are strata. Beta coefficients (hazard ratios) optimized for all strata are then fitted.

In your example, the model `coxph(Surv(futime, fustat) ~ age + strata(rx)` will output a hazard ratio for age in the presence of two (or more) hazards intrinsic to the levels of `rx`. If `rx` violated the proportional hazards assumption, for example, stratifying may help meet the PH assumption and provide more valid estimates for `age`. The effect of `rx` is not explicitly provided as a hazard ratio. Likelihood estimates for the model can be used to assess whether stratification by `rx` improved the model fit.

`coxph(Surv(futime, fustat) ~ age` will output a hazard ratio for age only, assuming that the hazard for different levels of `rx` are the same. In this model, the effect of `rx` is not explicitly modeled.

The model `coxph(Surv(futime, fustat) ~ age + rx` may be useful to consider. This model would provide estimates of the HR for `age` and `rx` with both present in the model ("adjusted for one another"). This would be different from `coxph(Surv(futime, fustat) ~ age + str(rx)` in that the unstratified model provides estimation of effect for both `age` and `rx` using a single underlying hazard.

Comment: In practice, how do we decide between these two approaches? stratify or adjust.

Comment: A reason to stratify is to (hopefully) correct violations of the PH assumption. In my practice, I also implement stratification when I don’t need to explicitly measure the effect of a variable but I know its values have vastly different underlying risks (eg, magnitude or “shape”; another form of PH violation). I could not find a related post with more detailed information. If you need a detailed answer, you may want to post a new question.

Comment: @ToddD, in the scenario where a variable isn't of interest as a covariate but might work as a stratifying variable, what criteria do you use to compare (a) `coxph(Surv(futime, fustat) ~ age)` with (b) `coxph(Surv(futime, fustat) ~ age + strata(rx))`? Do you fit both models and compare their AIC? Or does it make more sense to make that call based on context (e.g., use rx as a stratifying variable when we have biomedical reasons to expect that baseline hazard differs by rx)?

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the good answer from Todd B, here's a process you can follow, and some more of the background math.

#### A reasonable process to follow

1. Fit a Cox model (`fit.unstrat`) with all of the covariates and no stratifying variables.
2. Use `cox.zph(fit.unstrat)` to check for violations of the proportional hazards assumption. If you see e.g. `rx` has p<0.05, then `rx` violates the proportional hazards assumption and should not be included as a covariate in the Cox model. A reasonable follow-up is to try changing it to a stratifying variable, e.g., `fit.strat <- update(fit.unstrat, . ~ . - rx + strata(rx))`.
3. Next, it's appropriate to evaluate whether multiple models improve over the stratified model. The stratified Cox model allows the two `rx` groups to have different baseline hazards / baseline survivals, but it still only calculates a single effect $\beta_\text{age}$ of age on survival time. You can think of this as being the mean effect of age averaged across both `rx` groups. This raises a question: do you get a statistically significantly better fit when you allow the two `rx` groups to have different covariate effects ($\beta_\text{age, rx=2}$ and $\beta_\text{age, rx=1}$)? To answer this question, you:

   - fit the stratified model,
   - fit two separate Cox models for datasets subsetted by `rx`, and
   - compare them in a likelihood ratio test, where the p-value is $P\left(\chi^2_{(k-1)(q)}\right)>\ell_\text{stratified model} - \sum \ell_\text{unstratified models}$, with
     $k$ being the number of stratifying groups (just two here--`rx`=1 and `rx`=2), $q$ being the number of covariates (just 1 here--$z_\text{age}$), and $\ell$ is a model's log-likelihood.

Here's some sample code for the likelihood ratio tests. In this example (pretending `rx` violates the proportional hazards assumption), we wouldn't choose the multiple models, because while they improve the log likelihood, it's not a statistically significant improvement in the fit (p=0.1575):

```
library(survival)
fit.strat <- coxph(Surv(futime, fustat) ~ age + strata(rx), data=ovarian)
fit.grp1 <- coxph(Surv(futime, fustat) ~ age, subset=(rx==1), data=ovarian)
fit.grp2 <- coxph(Surv(futime, fustat) ~ age, subset=(rx==2), data=ovarian)

LL.strat <- fit.strat$loglik[2]
LL.unstrat <- fit.grp1$loglik[2] + fit.grp2$loglik[2]
    
X2 <- -2*(LL.strat - LL.unstrat)
n_groups <- length( unique(ovarian$rx) )
n_params <- length( fit.strat$coef )
p_val <- 1 - pchisq(X2, df=(n_groups-1)*n_params)
```

#### Background math

**Standard** Cox proportional hazards model:

$$h(t|Z) = h_0 \exp(\beta_\text{age}Z_\text{age} + \beta_\text{rx}Z_\text{rx})$$

```
fit.unstrat <- coxph(Surv(futime, fustat) ~ age + rx, data=ovarian)
```

- The quantity $h_0$ is called the baseline hazard. It corresponds with the baseline survival, which is the survival of the reference group whose covariates are all equal to 0.
- For a Cox model, the baseline hazard is estimated from the data non-parametrically (without assuming any distribution).
- The equation above implies:

  1. (hazard for `rx==2` group)/(hazard for `rx==1` group) is a constant. In other words, group 2's hazard is always higher/lower than group 1's hazard by a constant factor.
  2. The two `rx` groups have the same baseline hazard and baseline survival.

**Stratified** Cox proportional hazards model (you're actually fitting two equations that share a single $\beta_\text{age}$):

$$h_\text{rx=2}(t|Z) = h_{0,\text{rx=2}} \exp(\beta_\text{age}Z_\text{age}) \\ 
h_\text{rx=1}(t|Z) = h_{0,\text{rx=1}} \exp(\beta_\text{age}Z_\text{age})$$

```
fit.strat <- coxph(Surv(futime, fustat) ~ age + strata(rx), data=ovarian)
```

These equations imply:

1. The two rx groups have different baseline hazards / baseline survivals.
2. The two rx groups share a *single factor*, $\exp(\beta_\text{age})$, by which the hazard is always higher/lower for a 1-unit increase in age. In other words, we're specifying that both `rx` groups have the same $\beta_\text{age}$.

**Multiple models** (this is just a term I'm making up):

$$h_\text{rx=2}(t|Z) = h_{0,\text{rx=2}} \exp(\beta_\text{age, rx=2}Z_\text{age}) \\ 
h_\text{rx=1}(t|Z) = h_{0,\text{rx=1}} \exp(\beta_\text{age, rx=1}Z_\text{age})$$

```
fit.grp1 <- coxph(Surv(futime, fustat) ~ age, subset=(rx==1), data=ovarian)
fit.grp2 <- coxph(Surv(futime, fustat) ~ age, subset=(rx==2), data=ovarian)
```

#### Short note about time-dependent covariates

In addition to fitting a stratified model, another typical way to remediate a violation of the proportional hazards assumption is to (1) convert the violating variable into a time-dependent variable, and then (2) fit a new Cox PH model and check if the time-dependent covariate satisfies the PH assumption. Time-dependent covariates are an entirely different topic, but they can get invoked for the same reason as a stratified Cox model. Picking between these two often depends on context. If you think the two rx groups truly have different baseline survivals, then a stratified model makes sense. If there's a time component to `rx` (e.g., the data also contain a variable indicating how much time passed before they started treatment, or we think `rx` might have a cumulative effect such that the treatment only provides a benefit after some amount of time has passed), then a time-dependent variable might make more sense.